# Display extra text if the value in Advanced Custom Fields meets specific criteria

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields in a custom Wordpress template to power a review site.
My current code lets me display what I need, but now I want to show some extra text if any review get a score of 90 or more out of 100.

I use the following code to get all the posts and their ratings:

```
<?php 
  $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'=> 12,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type'=> 'movie',
        'meta_key' => 'movie_rating_john',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        ));
        if( $posts ): ?>
```

The score out of 100 is held in the `movie_rating_john` key, and I can output it like this:

```
<?php the_field('movie_rating_john'); ?>
```

Any ideas how I can add some text to this output if the value of the key is 90 or greater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value in `movie_rating_john` is only a number with no other text or characters, then you can do the following:

1. use `get_field` instead of `the_field` to save it in a variable
2. use `intval` to covert it to an integer
3. check the value to decide whether to add extra text

Putting it all together, you get the code below. Replace `<?php the_field('movie_rating_john'); ?>` with this.

```
<?php 
$rating_str = get_field('movie_rating_john');      // 1. Save value as variable
$rating_num = intval($rating_str);                 // 2. Convert to integer
if ($rating_num >= 90){                            // 3. Check value 
    // if the value is greater than or equal to 90, echo the number and your text
    echo $rating_num." this is your extra text here";
}
else{
    // if the value is less than 90, just echo the number
    echo $rating_num;
}
?>
```